# AWS Beanstalk integration with codecommit

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit

I have existing python project on AWS Beanstalk I decided to integrate it with codecommit but I get following err when I enter Branch name.

```
Enter Branch Name
***** Must have at least one commit to create a new branch with CodeCommit *****
(default is "develop"): develop 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fartash/.local/bin/eb", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/core/ebcore.py", line 150, in main
    app.run()
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cement/core/foundation.py", line 797, in run
    return_val = self.controller._dispatch()
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 472, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cement/core/controller.py", line 478, in _dispatch
    return func()
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/core/abstractcontroller.py", line 57, in default
    self.do_command()
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 172, in do_command
    branch = get_branch_interactive(repository)
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/controllers/initialize.py", line 575, in get_branch_interactive
    source_control.setup_new_codecommit_branch(branch_name=branch_name)
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/objects/sourcecontrol.py", line 313, in setup_new_codecommit_branch
    self.fetch_remote_branches(self.codecommit_remote_name)
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/objects/sourcecontrol.py", line 397, in fetch_remote_branches
    stdout, stderr, exitcode = self._run_cmd(['git', 'fetch', self.get_codecommit_presigned_remote_url(),
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/objects/sourcecontrol.py", line 434, in get_codecommit_presigned_remote_url
    signed_url = codecommit.create_signed_url(remote_url)
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/lib/codecommit.py", line 138, in create_signed_url
    password = _sign_codecommit_url(aws.get_region_name(), remote_url)
  File "/home/fartash/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ebcli/lib/codecommit.py", line 130, in _sign_codecommit_url
    signature = signer.signature(string_to_sign, request)
  File "/home/fartash/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 305, in signature
    k_date = self._sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'),
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: If you update to the latest EB CLI do you still get this error? You can upgrade the CLI with this command: `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I don't get any error after update